# How to search SQL Server table in C# Console app search function?

Tags: c#, string, search

I am fairly new to C# and have tried to make a warehouse console app. I would like to add a search function, to search for a products and see additional information about the product.

So far I have figured how to make a search function that searches for match in a text document.

And it's working just fine. The question is, how do I make it search in my `Products` table, column `ProductName` instead of in the `Data.txt` file?

My search function :

```
public static void searchMenu()
{
    start:
        string[] words = File.ReadAllText("Data.txt").Split(' ');

        Console.WriteLine("Type Product to search for:");
        string searchinput = Console.ReadLine();
        bool condition = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            if (words[i].Contains(searchinput) == true)
            {
                condition = true;
                break;
            } 
            else
            {
                condition = false;
            }
        }

        if (condition == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} found in database!", searchinput);
        } 
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} not found", searchinput);
        }

        goto start;
}
```

And my `Product` class :

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductStock { get; set; }
    public int ProductSubCategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ProductEmployeeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductCreatedDate { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public Product(int productid, string productname, int productstock, int productsubcategoryid, int productemployeeid)
    {
        ProductID = productid;
        ProductName = productname;
        ProductStock = productstock;
        ProductSubCategoryID = productsubcategoryid;
        ProductEmployeeID = productemployeeid;
        ProductCreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a text file you are searching, not a database. Could you show the database access code you have? Otherwise, please refer to [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview) to get started.

Comment: Yeap :-) That is correct, like i stated in the explanation of the question

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You could use entity framework, stored procedures, inline SQL. Here is a basic example where you fetch records from a db, fill an object and return a collection.

```
        public IEnumerable<Product> SearchProduct(string Criteria)
        {
            //initialize the connection string and products collection
            var connectionString = ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
            var products = new List<Product>();

            //initialize an sql connection, setup a parametized query and fill object    
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductName Like '%' + @ProductName + '%'"))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", Criteria);

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            //fill your object here
                        }
                    }
                }

                return products;
            }
        }
```